# Return everything except specific key in array php

Tags: php

Let's say i have an array below, I want to return everything except [year] key. How can i do that in php? Sorry if this is a newbie question.

```
 Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [filmId] => 61359
                    [url] => http://www.moviemeter.nl/film/61359
                    [title] => Unstoppable
                    [alternative_title] => 
                    [year] => 2011
                    [thumbnail] => http://www.moviemeter.nl/images/covers/thumbs/61000/61359.jpg
                    [average] => 0
                    [votes_count] => 0
                    [similarity] => 100.00
                    [directors_text] => geregisseerd door Richard Harrison
                    [actors_text] => met Chen Shilony, Ruben Crow en David Powell
                    [genres_text] => Drama / Komedie
                    [duration] => 90
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [filmId] => 87923
                    [url] => http://www.moviemeter.nl/film/87923
                    [title] => Unstoppable
                    [alternative_title] => 
                    [year] => 2011
                    [thumbnail] => http://www.moviemeter.nl/images/covers/thumbs/87000/87923.jpg
                    [average] => 0
                    [votes_count] => 0
                    [similarity] => 100.00
                    [directors_text] => geregisseerd door Example Director
                    [actors_text] => met Actor 1, Actor 2 en Actor 3
                    [genres_text] => Drama / Komedie
                    [duration] => 90
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [filmId] => 68593
                    [url] => http://www.moviemeter.nl/film/68593
                    [title] => Unstoppable
                    [alternative_title] => 
                    [year] => 2010
                    [thumbnail] => http://www.moviemeter.nl/images/covers/thumbs/68000/68593.jpg
                    [average] => 3.3
                    [votes_count] => 191
                    [similarity] => 100.00
                    [directors_text] => geregisseerd door Tony Scott
                    [actors_text] => met Denzel Washington, Chris Pine en Rosario Dawson
                    [genres_text] => Actie / Thriller
                    [duration] => 98
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [filmId] => 17931
                    [url] => http://www.moviemeter.nl/film/17931
                    [title] => Unstoppable
                    [alternative_title] => Nine Lives
                    [year] => 2004
                    [thumbnail] => http://www.moviemeter.nl/images/covers/thumbs/17000/17931.jpg
                    [average] => 2.64
                    [votes_count] => 237
                    [similarity] => 100.00
                    [directors_text] => geregisseerd door David Carson
                    [actors_text] => met Wesley Snipes, Jacqueline Obradors en Mark Sheppard
                    [genres_text] => Actie / Thriller
                    [duration] => 96
                )
        )
```

Sorry if this is a newbie question. Please help me out as i dont know if this is possible or not. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function remove_year_key(&$films) {
    foreach ($films as &$film) {
        unset($film["year"])
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely, you bet.

Comment: I didn't test it, but it should not work. need to pass `$film` variable by reference in `foreach`.